# Passing Object from JavaScript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

Good Evening,
Right now I have a project with back-end written in C#. I am trying to connect it to front-end JavaScript code. the method inside my js file:

```
var people = [{name: "Sam", age: 40}, {name: "Vivian", age: 20}]    
foo = function () {
            var url = "/api/folder/foo";
            $http({
                method: 'GET', url: url, params: {
                    version: "7.1",
                    ppl: people  <---- the passing that causes error
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("success!");
            }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert("server error");
            });
        };
```

That is calling C# code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("foo")]
    public List<LoopItem> foo(String version, List<Person> ppl){
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success!");
        return repository.foo( version, ppl);
    }
```

As you can see, my C# code takes as a parameter a string and List of Person, which is a simple object:

```
public class Person
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Int32 age { get; set; }
}
```

Although in my js code I tried to mimic the C# class Person, and created a list of objects with the same keys, the C# function does not seem to recognize the passed list of objects as list of Person from some reason. As the result, none of the debug "success" gets printed. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: try doing `JSON.stringify(people)`

Comment: You should be using a POST request instead of get.  Look at the attribute take you're using in the api call.

Comment: And is that angular's `$http`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't the `Person` class be annotated with Jsonattributes for it to be parsable from Json to a POCO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JSON encoding/decoding.

```
var people = [{name: "Sam", age: 40}, {name: "Vivian", age: 20}]    
foo = function () {
            var myJsonPeople = JSON.stringify(people);
            var url = "/api/folder/foo";
            $http({
                method: 'POST', url: url, params: {
                    version: "7.1",
                    ppl: myJsonPeople <---- the passing that causes error
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("success!");
            }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert("server error");
            });
        };
```

On server side you will need to receive this data as json and then convert it to objects list.

```
[HttpPost]
public string foo(string jsonList)
{
     //Convert string to JSON object
     //Foreach loop for conversion to objects
}
```

Comment: how do i convert it back to objects list in the c# code? also, would that involve changing the type of parameter that foo() takes?

Comment: @QuangTran To convert back to objects you have to write your own function. Run a loop for json received and make new object and set its properties using json data. The parameter should be json type i guess.

Comment: Actually you are passign json from javascript to C# so it do not have any knowledge about your object definition that is why it can not convert it to objects implicitly.

Comment: @QuangTran See my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your C# controller is expecting a `POST` request (from the `[HttpPost]` attribute) instead of a `GET` request.  You'll need to change your javascript request accordingly.

That looks like angular's `$http` service.  So this should work:

```
var url = "/api/folder/foo";
var params = {
                   version: "7.1",
                   ppl: people  
             };
$http.post(url, params)
    .success( //etc
```

This uses [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), which is a shortcut to making a `POST` request.

Comment: Yup, i made a mistake in the original code. Changing it to post method resolved the error. However, I am still not able to pass the people list. Even if it exists in js code, when I try to pass it to C#, the debug line says that it is null.

Comment: Hmm.  That sounds like a JSON issue.  Not sure if that's a problem on the javascript side or the C# Controller.